# SOAP problem in Classic ASP

Tags: xml, soap, asp-classic

There is a webservice at http://www.lasertools.co.uk/webservice/getCatalogue.asmx which I need to use which accepts SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2 requests but I have no experience of these with classic ASP; I have read several articles about it and tried some of the methods mentioned in those articles but I just can't seem to get it to work. The best I have managed so far is a response from the server which says 404 page not found. Here is the ASP page I cam currently trying:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<%

    Dim objXML
    Dim postUrl
    Dim DataToSend
    Dim DataParms
    Dim DataReceived
    Dim Status

    DataToSend = ""
    DataParms = ""
    postUrl = "http://www.lasertools.co.uk/webservice/GetProductCategories"

    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

    objXML.Open "POST", postUrl, False 
    objXML.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8" 
objXML.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://www.lasertools.co.uk/webservice/GetProductCategories" 
    objXML.setRequestHeader "MessageType", "CALL"
    SOAPRequest = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> "
    SOAPRequest = SOAPRequest & "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"""
    SOAPRequest = SOAPRequest & " xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"""
    SOAPRequest = SOAPRequest & " xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">"
    SOAPRequest = SOAPRequest & " <soap:Body>"
    SOAPRequest = SOAPRequest & " <getProductCategories xmlns=""http://www.lasertools.co.uk/webservice"" />"
    SOAPRequest = SOAPRequest & " </soap:Body>"
    SOAPRequest = SOAPRequest & " </soap:Envelope>"

    objXML.send SOAPRequest 
    DataReceived = objXML.responseText

    Dim oXml
    Set oXml = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")

    oXml.LoadXml (DataReceived)
    oXML.async = False

    Set objLst = oXml.getElementsByTagName("*")
    if objLst.Length = 0 then
%>
        <br />NO CHOICES<br />
<%
        response.write DataReceived & "<br />"
    else
        AvailableChoices = 0
    For Each xmlItem In objLst
        For Each xmlItem2 In xmlItem.childNodes
            if xmlItem.childNodes(0).NodeName = "#text" then
           AvailableChoices = AvailableChoices + 1
           DisplayVal = xmlItem.childNodes(0).text
%>
        <%=DisplayVal%><br />
<%
        end if
        Next
    Next
    end if
%>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The 404 response is to be expected; you're not posting to the right URL:

```
postUrl = "http://www.lasertools.co.uk/webservice/getCatalogue.asmx"
```

Just check out the example on http://www.lasertools.co.uk/webservice/getCatalogue.asmx?op=getProductCategories.

Of course, there might be more problems with the XML you're sending, but this site removes anything between brackets unless you [mark it as code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was that simple - I tried dozens of combinations of code ! Thanks

Comment: No problem Mike.  Could you accept this answer then?  (Click the checkbox left of this answer).